# Some way to create 1 million relationships with a neo4j query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, load-csv

With this query I am importing 75000 nodes from my csv file. (Category)

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM "file:///prodcategory.csv" AS row 
CREATE (:Category {id: row.idProdCategory, name: row.name, idRestaurant: row.idRestaurant});
```

And with this query I am also importing 1 million nodes from my csv file (Product)

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM "file:///products.csv" AS row 
CREATE (:Product {id: row.idProduct, idProductCategory: row.idProductCategory,name: row.name,idRestaurant:row.idRestaurant ,description: row.description, price: row.price, shipping_price: row.shippingPrice});
```

I am using this query to create the relationship between id -> category and idProductCategory -> products.

```
MATCH (category:Category {id: category.id})
MATCH (Product:Product {idProductCategory: Product.idProductCategory})
WHERE Product.idProductCategory=category.id
MERGE (category)-[:OF_CATEGORY]->(Product);
```

This query only creates 2999 relationships and I do not believe the 1 million relationships I should create, please if there is a method or configuration to be able to create more than 1 million relationships please help me I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure you have indexes on `Product.idProductCategory`.

I assume that the category id is unique across categories.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (category:Category) ASSERT category.id IS UNIQUE;
```

I assume that there are multiple products with the same category ID.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Product(idProductCategory);
```

Then you can simply match each category and then for each category find the appropriate products and create the relationships.

```
// match all of your categories
MATCH (category:Category)

// then with each category find all the products
WITH category 
MATCH (Product:Product {idProductCategory: category.id })

// and then create the 
MERGE (category)-[:OF_CATEGORY]->(Product);
```

If you are running into memory constraints you could use the APOC periodic commit to wrap your query...

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("
  MATCH (category:Category)
  WITH category 
  MATCH (Product:Product {idProductCategory: category.id })
  MERGE (category)-[:OF_CATEGORY]->(Product)
",{limit:10000})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help apparently I have problems with my memory that I have 4G ram can solve this in some configuration I am linux 1.

This is the message that shows me:

Comment: There is not enough memory to perform the current task. Please try increasing 'dbms.memory.heap.max_size' in the neo4j configuration (normally in 'conf/neo4j.conf' or, if you you are using Neo4j Desktop, found through the user interface) or if you are running an embedded installation increase the heap by using '-Xmx' command line flag, and then restart the database.

Comment: you could wrap it with apoc.periodic.commit

Comment: I get the following error when applying the query with apoc:                                 {java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space -> 1}                                         
I need to thank you for your help

Comment: have you extended your heap in the `conf/neo4j.conf` file?

Comment: yes                                                                                                                          dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=1512m
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=1512m                                                              dbms.memory.pagecache.size=10g

Comment: Thanks for the help I was able to create the relationships thanks to your help.

Answer (score 1):

try to change your query to this... you are using too many filters in your query

check [docs for MATCH](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/)

```
MATCH (category:Category),(Product:Product)
WHERE Product.idProductCategory=category.id
MERGE (category)-[:OF_CATEGORY]->(Product)
```

you can also just change your second import query, so you do not need a separate query for linking.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM "file:///products.csv" AS row 
CREATE (p:Product {id: row.idProduct, name: row.name,idRestaurant:row.idRestaurant ,description: row.description, price: row.price, shipping_price: row.shippingPrice})
MATCH (c:Category{id:row.idProductCategory}
MERGE (p)-[:OF_CATEGORY]->(c)
```